# Views formatting: liquid number of columns?

Tags: views, theming

I have a Views page that creates a 3-column grid layout.  These look just fine on a desktop browser.

On a mobile browser, each column is too thin to usefully read the text that's displayed, and it looks pretty awful, even if I use media queries to scale the text down.  I'd like to go to a single-column layout on these sorts of screens.  Is there a good way to do this?  Ideally, a CSS-only approach would be best, since I've managed to get my layout fluid using only CSS thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to move away from using a table layout to one that uses divs instead, e.g an 'unformatted list' views style.

It's quite easy by piling a set of floated divs into a container.

If the container width changes, the number of items per 'row' also change.

e.g, something like this for the view items.

```
.views-row{
  float:left;
  margin:8px;
}
```

Comment: That works great, thanks David.  I don't suppose you know of a way to force the matter so that if three columns don't fit on one page, it'll go straight to one columns instead of via two?  The content looks pretty awful in a two column layout.

Comment: @JonTopper yes, you can set the 'width' of the views row in your responsive css with media queries. e.g width:33% or width 100% for 3 col and 1 col